# Error building nextjs app on AWS Amplify: Could not initialize platform for 'staging': Access Denied

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

```
\# Starting phase: build
2023-05-03T02:31:47.363Z \[INFO\]: \[33mNote: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory\[39m
2023-05-03T02:31:47.908Z \[WARNING\]: - Initializing your environment: staging
2023-05-03T02:31:47.994Z \[WARNING\]: ✖ Initializing your environment: staging
2023-05-03T02:31:47.994Z \[WARNING\]: ✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
2023-05-03T02:31:47.995Z \[INFO\]:  Could not initialize platform for 'staging': Access Denied
Resolution: Review the error message and stack trace for additional information.
Learn more at: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/troubleshooting/
2023-05-03T02:31:48.007Z \[INFO\]:
2023-05-03T02:31:48.007Z \[INFO\]: Session Identifier: 8fed5aa7-be23-4e0f-81a7-2d217bbbd640
2023-05-03T02:31:48.056Z \[ERROR\]: !!! Build failed
2023-05-03T02:31:48.056Z \[INFO\]: Please check the supported SSR features to find if your build failure is related to an unsupported feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-Amplify-support.html#supported-unsupported-features. You may also find this troubleshooting guide useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html
2023-05-03T02:31:48.056Z \[ERROR\]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-05-03T02:31:48.056Z \[INFO\]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-05-03T02:31:48.057Z \[INFO\]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "amplifyapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^4.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.1.4",
    "eslint": "8.39.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.4",
    "next": "13.3.4",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  }
}
```

- While following the "Build a Full-Stack React Application" tutorial
- This is after I push to github
- My directories are not configured correctly maybe?
- Access Denied means that my AWS account isn't allowed to do this somehow?

Answer (score 3):

This issue arises due to not setting up the role for backend deployment. Goto your Iam>Roles and create a new role and add Amplify>Backend Deployment role to it. Now go back to your amplify general setting page and choose the role you just created. Now it should fix this...

Comment: I have managed to solve this problem, but I took some minutes to figure where to use the role I created. You should go to Amplify, then  the app you are trying to deploy > App Settings > General, click Edit and Change the Service role field to the role you just created.